# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

I have the following code to make sure that api.example.com will call example.com/api.php. It works on my localhost, but not on my website.

```
RewriteEngine On

 # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^ api.php [L]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ website.php [L]
```

The browser returns the eror ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. Whats the problem and how do I fix this?

Comment: That's not how it works. You need to create the api subdomain in your dns zone to get it resolved.

Comment: how do i do that? i get a feeling its the CNAME but i dont know how to use it

Comment: You create a CNAME `api` record for example.com and set his destination to `example.com.`

Comment: i have done so. any ip changes that need to be made?

Comment: It take some time (up to 3 hours, depends of the TTL) to be effective. Try again in few hours. You can then check your cname records on [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/) with the command `cname:example.com`

Comment: okay. but i dont need to do anything else, right?

Comment: To create the subdomain no.

Comment: okay i see thank you. i will post if it works!